# Extbase Model: setSysLanguageUid not working

Tags: typo3, extbase

I created an extbase model and try to set the sys_language_uid field when creating a new item. For some reason though, it is completely ignored and always set to 0, even when the value I try to enter is definitely 1.

My Model looks like this:

```
class Ad extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity {

    /**
     * sysLanguageUid
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $sysLanguageUid;


    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getSysLanguageUid()
    {
        return $this->sysLanguageUid;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $sysLanguageUid
     */
    public function setSysLanguageUid($sysLanguageUid)
    {
        $this->sysLanguageUid = $sysLanguageUid;
    }

    // ... etc. 
}
```

and in my controller all I try to do is this:

```
$ad = new Ad(); 
$ad->setSysLanguageUid($GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_language_uid);
$ad->setSomeOtherParam('xxx');
$this->adRepository->add($ad);
```

The other param is saved just fine. sys_language_uid exists in ext_tables.sql and in the TCA:

```
'columns' => array(
    'sys_language_uid' => array(
        'exclude' => 1,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xml:LGL.language',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'foreign_table' => 'sys_language',
            'foreign_table_where' => 'ORDER BY sys_language.title',
            'items' => array(
                array('LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xml:LGL.allLanguages', -1),
                array('LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xml:LGL.default_value', 0)
            ),
        ),
    ),  
    'some_other_field' => ....
)
```

Why is setSysLanguageUid not working? Any hints?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

it seems like setSysLanguageUid doesn't work because typo3 is UNNECESSARILY CONVOLUTED AND DIFFICULT. For some reason it is possible to set the language ID but only by defining and using these getters and setters:

```
/**
 * _languageUid
 * @var int
 */
protected $_languageUid;

/**
 * @param int $_languageUid
 * @return void
 */
public function set_languageUid($_languageUid) {
    $this->_languageUid = $_languageUid;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function get_languageUid() {
    return $this->_languageUid;
}
```

I swear, typo3 is gonna give me a heart attack one of these days....

Comment: I've made some kind of a duplicate of your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37706042/set-sys-language-uid-in-an-extbase-command-controller

Comment: I've tried simply pasting the above code into my model and doing `$entry->set_languageUid = -1;`, but that's probably not enough yet. Is this really supposed to write into `tx_myext_domain_model_item.sys_language_uid`?

Comment: yes but you need to do $entry->set_languageUid(-1);

Comment: eeew... sorry I didn't spot that! It works! How does TYPO3 / Extbase know that `_languageUid` refers to `sys_language_uid`? And how did you find that out? And how's your heart :-) ?

Comment: it took me hours to find it. my heart hates typo3 :D but happy to help :)

Comment: As of 2021, you can simply use `setSyslanguageUid()` on all Entities :-)

Answer (score 1):

Actually all that you need is a getter and a setter since you enherit the `protected $_languageUid;` property from `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity` that it self enherits it from `TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractDomainObject`

```php
/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getSysLanguageUid(): int
{
    return $this->_languageUid;
}

/**
 * @param int $sysLanguageUid
 * @return Ad
 */
public function setSysLanguageUid(int $sysLanguageUid)
{
    $this->_languageUid = $sysLanguageUid;

    return $this;
}
```

You could also do it without any change to your model since `TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractDomainObject` gives you a getter `_getProperty()`

```php
// With your custom getters and setters
$ad->getSysLanguageUid()

// With the getter from AbstractDomainObject
$ad->_getProperty('_languageUid')
```

Answer (score 0):

From 2021 and TYPO3 10.x

```
/**
 * @var int
 */
protected $sysLanguageUid;

/**
 * Get sys language
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getSysLanguageUid()
{
    return $this->_languageUid;
}

/**
 * Set sys language
 *
 * @param int $sysLanguageUid language uid
 */
public function setSysLanguageUid($sysLanguageUid)
{
    $this->_languageUid = $sysLanguageUid;
}
```