# Set sys_language_uid in an extbase command controller

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-7.x

I have a command controller (an importer) run by scheduler, which should persist data as such:

```
foreach ($items as $item){
  // store it
  $entry = $this->objectManager->get('STUBR\Importer\Domain\Model\Item');
  $entry->setTitle($item['Title']);
  $entry->setData(json_encode($item));
  // manually set the storage page (defined in scheduler form)
  $entry->setPid($itemStoragePid); // works
  // manually set the language (defined in scheduler form)
  // EDIT
  // $entry->setSysLanguageUid = -1; // had typo
  $entry->set_languageUid(-1); // works
  // END EDIT
  $this->itemRepository->add($entry);
}
```

While neither pid nor sys_language_uid are set in the model, `setPid` behaves as expected, but `setSysLanguageUid` does not.

I'm aware that something is or was not quite right with                                setSysLanguageUid() in extbase (https://forge.typo3.org/issues/45873), although I wasn't able to grasp the problem entirely.

How do I manually store into the sys_language_uid column?

PS: I've tried [Extbase Model: setSysLanguageUid not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33781458/extbase-model-setsyslanguageuid-not-working/33798615) but probably I missed something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's solved, I had a typo above

Solution from @Chi at https://stackoverflow.com/a/33798615/160968

```
/**
 * languageUid
 * @var int
 */
protected $languageUid;

/**
 * @param int $languageUid
 * @return void
 */
public function setLanguageUid($languageUid) {
    $this->languageUid = $languageUid;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getLanguageUid() {
    return $this->languageUid;
}
```

And then `$entry->setLanguageUid(-1);`

Comment: I'd say it is `setLanguageUid`, to stick with the convention ;)

Comment: Ah, I thought that underscore had some hidden functionality! So you mean keep the getters/setters, but name them conventionally?

Comment: Yes. And for those thinking this solution is not working.. it works for setting the `sys_language_uid`, but it may not persist as such to the database because of the datamapper.

Comment: This no longer works for me. Im specifically asking extbase for an object in a given language, $query->equals('sysLanguageUid',5), but extbase returns the default language. Any update on how to use this?

Comment: You do use `$query->matching()` around `$query->equals()`, right? Just asking because I just learnt that. I searched the code in my sites and found it's in a TYPO3 7 install. Does your "no longer" refer to 8.x?