# Select records from other languages in a scheduler task

Tags: typo3, extbase

I am developing an extension, which provides a scheduler task. In this task an API is triggered and the results are going to be written to the database. So far there is no problem.

But the whole typo3 (8.7 with php7.2) page have multiple languages. So I have to save all the API objects in their different language. This does not make any difficulties for the insert process, but in the update process I could not select the correct languages.

Some mysterios things I still solved, like the `sys_language_uid` parameter, which have to be `_languageUid` ([more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33781458/extbase-model-setsyslanguageuid-not-working)) or that I do not find any solution for getting all possible languages from the `sys_language` table without using a own doctrine querybuilder over the `ConnectionPool`. (I also add the default language as an entry)

Now to the main problem, which I could not solve yet. After debugging the core I get, that the queries I build with the repository are correct.

the repository:

```
$query = $this->createQuery();
$query->getQuerySettings()->setIgnoreEnableFields(true);
$query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectSysLanguage(false);
$query->matching(
    $query->logicalAnd(
        $query->equals('identifier', $identifier),
        $query->equals('sys_language_uid', $languageUid)
    )
);
```

the resulting query is:

```
SELECT `TABLE`.* FROM `TABLE` `T`
WHERE (
    (`T`.`identifier` = :dcValue1) 
    AND (`T`.`sys_language_uid` = :dcValue2)
) AND (`T`.`deleted` = 0)
```

Now I try to get the parent object from the database to proceed an update. The whole update-mapping is unit-tested and all debug outputs confirm that everything works fine.

I look back to core and find at [TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Storage\Typo3DbBackend::class](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/v8.7.15/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Generic/Storage/Typo3DbBackend.php#L613) on line 612:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
     // If current row is a translation select its parent
    if (isset($tableName) && isset($GLOBALS['TCA'][$tableName])
        && isset($GLOBALS['TCA'][$tableName]['ctrl']['languageField'])
        && isset($GLOBALS['TCA'][$tableName]['ctrl']['transOrigPointerField'])
        && $tableName !== 'pages_language_overlay'
    ) {
        if (isset($row[$GLOBALS['TCA'][$tableName]['ctrl']['transOrigPointerField']])
            && $row[$GLOBALS['TCA'][$tableName]['ctrl']['transOrigPointerField']] > 0
        ) {
            $queryBuilder = $this->connectionPool->getQueryBuilderForTable($tableName);
            $queryBuilder->getRestrictions()->removeAll();
            $row = $queryBuilder->select($tableName . '.*')
                ->from($tableName)
                ->where(
                    $queryBuilder->expr()->eq(
                        $tableName . '.uid',
                        $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter(
                            $row[$GLOBALS['TCA'][$tableName]['ctrl']['transOrigPointerField']],
                            \PDO::PARAM_INT
                        )
                    ),
                    $queryBuilder->expr()->eq(
                        $tableName . '.' . $GLOBALS['TCA'][$tableName]['ctrl']['languageField'],
                        $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter(0, \PDO::PARAM_INT)
                    )
                )
                ->setMaxResults(1)
                ->execute()
                ->fetch();
        }
    }
...
```

Like the comment on line 613 says, the row from the database will be overwritten in this foreach. All xdebug-data confirm that. If I disable the `transOrigPointerField` in my TCA it will work like expected, but the backend-view could not assign the multiple languages to one parent element.

I also tried to delete the TCA entry just for the scheduler task, but the TCA is cached and no temporary overwrite is possible.

Am I doing something wrong, or is it just a bug?

### update

Take a look at the simplified [example](https://github.com/freshp/typo3_schedulertask_add-multiple-language)

Answer (score 0):

I was editing the TYPO3-core for version 8.7 (branch `TYPO3_8-7` after tag 8.7.19) now. At the file typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Generic/Storage/Typo3DbBackend.php on line 618 I additonally check the respectSysLangauge option so the new check will be:

```
// If current row is a translation select its parent
if (isset($tableName) && isset($GLOBALS['TCA'][$tableName])
      && isset($GLOBALS['TCA'][$tableName]['ctrl']['languageField'])
      && isset($GLOBALS['TCA'][$tableName]['ctrl']['transOrigPointerField'])
      && $tableName !== 'pages_language_overlay'
      && true === $querySettings->getRespectSysLanguage()
) {
```

After this I started the TYPO3-testsuite for this part of TYPO3 and everthing seems to be OK (all tests passed) and my problem is fixed. I dont know how to contribute correctly without spending hours with reading the whole [contribution guide](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ContributionWorkflowGuide/).